# Got an error when removing Apple WatchKit from the project

Tags: ios, plist, apple-watch, xcode9.4

I intend to remove Apple WatchKit from the project.

I have done the steps of removing WatchKit extension from "Target Dependencies" and  "Embed App Extensions". However, I got an error when building my project:

> "error: could not read data from '/Users/kevin/swift/toDoList /toDoListWatch/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

This may due to the fact that I deleted all related WatchOS files in Finder.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?